# How to use re.sub function for the following?

Tags: python, substitution, python-re

i would like to substitute the below lines to,

```
ABC+::A1
CDE+:A1A1A1
```

Expected Output:

```
ABC+::A1
TIM+++2020:11:21:12:51+ZZZ
ABC++ADDEDTIME
CDE+:A1A1A1
```

I would like to add the following lines between the above two lines. Please note that from the above lines, A1/A1A1A1 is a variable will keep changing but the first three alpha character remains the same. Hence no matter what is mentioned after the colon (+::), the below two lines must be added,

Lines to be added

```
TIM+++2020:11:21:12:51+ZZZ
ABC++ADDEDTIME
```

Comment: read line by line and keep a buffer of the last 2 lines read and check if the last 2 lines match your testcase and if so output some additional lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could make good use of re like this shown below:

```
import re
regex = r"^(ABC\+::[A-Z0-9]+\n)(?=^CDE\+:[A-Z0-9]+)"
test_str = ("ABC+::A1\n"
    "CDE+:A1A1A1")
subst = "\\1TIM+++2020:11:21:12:51+ZZZ\\nABC++ADDEDTIME\\n"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
if result:
    print(result)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TF2rBs/1)

Basically, the regex pattern matches ABC+::ALPHANUM{1, or more} followed by CDE+:ALPHANUM{1, or more} and substitutes the first match in brackets back, and adds line breaks and the new strings after it.